# Vacuum state for an asymmetric space

Tags: hilbert-space, vacuum, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I am studying Bunch-Davies vacuum. In the derivation it is important the symmetry of the background space: the vacuum is the state which is invariant under the isometries of the space.

But what if the space had no symmetry? How could one pick a vacuum state?

Answer (score 1):

If there is no symmetry, there is in general no way to pick a vacuum state, because a state that is invariant under time translation in one set of coordinates is in general time-dependent in a different set of coordinates, and since there is no symmetry, there is no preferred coordinate system.